# The given path's format is not supported is given when using dynamic path in export csv

Tags: powershell, csv, export

**Problem Statement:
| Export-Csv -Path ($Path+$exportCSVName+$CurrentDate+$FileType) -Append**

Declared variables for  $Path ,$exportCSVName,$CurrentDate and $FileType

if I am running only ($Path+$exportCSVName+$CurrentDate+$FileType) it returns correct data but while executing it along with code path not supported is given

Comment: Please post the exact and full error message inside the question. What value is shown when you execute `($Path+$exportCSVName+$CurrentDate+$FileType)` on its own?

Comment: The syntax works for me. So there's something wrong with one or more of those variables. My guess is that `$CurrentDate` contains `:` characters.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Yes correct it  contains : characters ,now i have replaced them with . or - and it worked.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `$CurrentDate` contains a `:` character. That character needs to be replaced with a legal filename character. Otherwise, the syntax of the following is correct:

```
$data | Export-Csv -Path ($Path+$exportCSVName+$CurrentDate+$FileType) -NoType
```